# Having a hard time adding third party library in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

Having a hard time adding third party library .js file with ionic 2, I'm getting "module not found". All though I have installed it by typing "npm install progressbar.js". My home.ts has the correct import statement: "import * as ProgressBar from 'progressbar.js';", and the progressbar.js folder is under node_modules folder.

Am I missing something ?

Btw. I'm using Atom.

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "!node_modules/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/global",
    "typings/global.d.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess you have to add the typescript definition too, isn't the step you missed? Furthermore, not an answer, just a thought. If you dont' mind to display your users just a waiting animation without indication of how the current job is progressing, you could just use the build in component from Ionic "Loading"